# How Can I Improve the Font Rendering In Firefox

Tags: debian, fonts, firefox

My font rendering in Firefox looks terrible on pages such as facebook.com and twitter.com:

[image]

I'm running Debian 8 and fiddling with hardware acceleration, and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think Firefox uses the default font for these things. You can edit the default font from Firefox preferences. Is this what you asked for?

Comment: It still didn't change things. The fonts look great when I don't allow sites to choose their own but this messes up some icons. Any other suggestions?

Comment: This is just with Firefox and not a system problem?

Comment: Right. Everything looks great on chromium

Comment: Probably you have the bitmap version of Helvetica installed

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I've had this issue for ages, maybe it's time to do something about it!

It comes done to `ClearType`, Microsoft and patents from what I read. Most *nix distro's disable any patent protected font rendering by default.

Read about Debian and fonts [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Fonts), you want `Subpixel-hinting and Font-smoothing` section.

There's a config file on that page but I will add here for future reference. Create a file called `.fonts.conf` in your home directory, and add the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="rgba">
   <const>rgb</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="hinting">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
   <const>hintslight</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
  <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="lcdfilter">
    <const>lcddefault</const>
  </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

Comment: If I could, I would have upvoted this 50 times. Thanks for such an elegant solution (still usable in 2016 using Debian Jessie and GNOME)!!!

Comment: Still working by 2017, Debian Jessie and KDE. Thanks!

Comment: Still working in 2017 on Stretch too!

Comment: I can confirm this in 2019. Thank you!

Comment: A more "modern" location for the file would be `${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/fontconfig/fonts.conf` or `${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/fontconfig/conf.d/99-improved-rendering.conf`.  Most of the time [`${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}`](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) is the `.config` subdirectory under the home directory, e.g. `/home/gwillie/.config`.

Comment: Still working in 2020. On Manjaro 20.2 KDE. Put it in `/etc/fonts/conf.d/99-improved-rendering.conf`.

Comment: I think that most of this should be set by default in Arch (through symlinks in /etc/fonts/conf.d) or should be the default and thus not changed.

But, for some reason, this has helped in my case too. I run arch in a vmware workstation VM.

Comment: Works in 2021 on Fedora 34!

Comment: Still working in 2021 (especially for Firefox)

Answer (score 9):

These sites use Helvetica as their font. On most Debian systems it's not an outline font, but raster one. You can disable bitmapped fonts as the last stage of font configuration dialog:

```
$ dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig-config
```

Comment: I just ran this without changing any of the answers, and it improved fonts instantly! (maybe dist upgrade caused some problems)

Answer (score 1):

I've improved mine these days using fontconfig-infinality. Looks great!

The first topic of [this](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=88545) forum shows how to do it. Do not use the first method of the link(compilation), use the deb files below it. Install with

```
dpkg -i *.deb
```

and then

```
bash /etc/fonts/infinality/infctl.sh setstyle
```

choose option 2 (infinality)

DONE!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the suggestions above with Firefox 75 and KDE 5.6 (Arch based Antergos linux) with no success or only slight improvement. Only after changing the Firefox font settings to *Fira Sans* and the fonts in Firefox gui (tabs, menus, etc) finally started to look sharp, almost as good as in Chromium based browsers. I could not replicate this with any other font no matter how I've set hinting and aliasing.

**Menu** -> **Preferences** -> **Language and Appearance** section, and there I changed teh **Default font** to Fira Sans. You can play a bit more with the Advance section. You can try Fira Mono as monotype font etc.

Answer (score 0):

This won't help many people, but ...

For me it was some *ancient* Adobe.pfb files in my .fonts directory.  Specifically Helvetica.pfb .

If you have Adobe Postscript files from the 90's laying about, have a look with:

```
fc-match -s Helvetica | grep -i Helvetica
```

and see if anything lurks.  I 100% would have expected @Perlence 's answer to fix this, but apparently .PFB is an exception.  I don't see this problem in Chromium-based browsers, so maybe Firefox is handling it?

Anyway, the good news is as soon as I removed it, I was able to switch back to my test tab (archive.org) and as soon as Firefox reloaded the DOM it was perfect.  In previous iterations I quit Firefox, logged out of my X11 session, rebuilt the font cache, etc. but none of that was ultimately needed.

See here for a before and after for identification/comparison:

[image: archive.org before and after removing PostScript bitmap]