# Infinality and Firefox/Thundebird

Tags: debian, fonts, cinnamon

I’m currently using Debian Stretch (9.1) on my Laptop (HP ProBook 640 G1 with Intel HD 4600) and Cinnamon 3.2 as desktop environment. While trying to get the best results for font rendering, my first attempt was the little script found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/226926), which was quite useful.

However, the usage of the package `fontconfig-infinality` yields much better results. My problem with this package is now that it has awful consequences for Mozilla programs like Firefox or Thunderbird as shown in the picture:

[image]

Any ideas how to get a proper font rendering for Firefox and Thunderbrid while using Infinality?

Comment: Your fonts seem perfect okay to me. Infinality has a lot of finetuning settings, I forgot where are they (because everything is fine by me with the default settings).

Comment: You may have some tips [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/226831/52236).

Comment: I think Firefox/Thunderbird (and also VLC/Chromium/Alacarte) are not obeying the ›Hinting Slight‹ option from Cinnamon and perform a full hinting.