# How to fix Fontconfig error: failed reading config file

Tags: debian, firefox, fontconfig, snap

On Debian testing, whenever I run a browser from the terminal, I get four lines of the following error:

```
Fontconfig error: failed reading config file
```

This doesn't seem to cause any problems in any application, only in Firefox Quantum installed via `snap` font rendering doesn't work correctly, just like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451970/firefox-quantum-on-debian-stretch-font-rendering-problems) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226831/how-can-i-improve-the-font-rendering-in-firefox).

I have already tried all the steps mentioned in the two posts, apart from installing the tar, since I'd like to keep the `snap` version. When I first installed the browser, I had rendering issues on more websites (like Stackoverflow), but installing Microsoft core fonts fixed this. Now, the issue seems to be with Helvetica only, however, `fc-match Helvetica` shows that Helvetica is correctly matched with Arial.

So my conclusion is that somehow the "snap Firefox" is not able to read the `fontconfig` files (firefox-esr works fine, just like Opera and other browsers). I think the problem is not confined to Firefox Quantum though, because the error appears when I run another browser from command line as well. It just doesn't cause any issue there.

So the question is really how to fix the `fontconfig` setup? I have already reinstalled and ran `dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig-config`.

Comment: Seems a more informative error message [is coming](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106497) in a future fontconfig version.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at `/etc/fonts/conf.avail` and `/etc/fonts/conf.d` . I came across this question because I had the same problem. Finally

`FC_DEBUG=1024 fc-cache 2>&1|less`

did not tell anything helpful. So I ran the following command looking for missing configuration files.

`FC_DEBUG=1024 strace fc-cache 2>&1|less`

It turned out that the configuration file from the fonts-guru-extra package was messed up. It was stored as `/etc/fonts/conf.avail/65-0-fonts-guru-extra.conf/65-0-fonts-guru-extra.conf` and the symlink from `/etc/fonts/conf.avail/65-0-fonts-guru-extra.conf` was somehow broken. At least it was not a file.

So I ran `dpkg --force-depends --purge fonts-guru-extra` and dpkg complained about a non-empty directory `/etc/fonts/conf.avail/65-0-fonts-guru-extra.conf` 
I deleted this directory by hand and ran

`apt-get install fonts-guru-extra`

and afterwards the error message was gone.

Comment: Actually there are two bug reports regarding this problem: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=854165 and https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=866051

Answer (score 1):

This worked in my case (probably, it's a more universal solution):

```
# dpkg --force-depends --purge fontconfig-config
# aptitude install fontconfig-config
# dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig-config
```

For me the problem was caused by downgrading fontconfig from 2.13 to 2.11 on debian stretch.